# Every class is implicitly a subclass of Object Java

Tags: java

I'm reading Java Inheritance Docs and got this paragraph, but I don't what is mean of this. Can any body explain?

> Excepting Object, which has no superclass, every class has one and
>   only one direct superclass (single inheritance). In the absence of any
>   other explicit superclass, every class is implicitly a subclass of
>   Object.

**Edited**

Another point related to this question:

And due to Object is superclass, NetBeans show me extra method list when I try to call any Member of class with object reference? All those methods are declared in Object class?

Comment: Every class, except Object, is a sub-class of Object. If you understand what sub-class means what is your doubt?

Comment: @PeterLawrey Where is Object class? I was just confused about object of class. and Why java use this?

Comment: @LetDoit check the answer for why NetBeans shows Object class methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meaning of **implicitly** - *suggested though not directly expressed.*

If samething applied in Java classes. Consider there is a class called `Test`.

If you write

```
public class Test {....}
```

That is equivalent to

```
  public class Test extends Object {....}
```

Though you didn't write it, it's equivalent to it. You need not to write extends `Object` manually. Internally JVM treats that your class is extends `Object`. Since the part after extends is your class, here `Object` is your super class.

But,

When you write

```
  public class Test extends BigTest{....}
```

Things changed now. You are telling `BigTest` is my parent class. That means you are implicitly writing yourself that `BigTest` is my parent. Interesting part here is though BigTest is your direct `Parent` class, internally `Object` also your `Parent`.

So now you have 2 parent classes. One is `BigTest` which you mentioned and other is Object. If you didn't mention anything, only `Object` is your Parent.

**Edit :**

This is the reason that you will see extra list of method when you will try to call any member of class with object-reference. Those methods are declared in Object class.

> why java do this? any feature of this?

Yes. There are benefits of it. Main reason is to reduce the code duplication.

Continue reading here ....  [**Why Object as super class in Java** ?](http://codeinventions.blogspot.in/2014/08/reason-behind-making-object-as-super.html)

Comment: @SURESH why java do this? any feature of this? where is Object class? which package?

Comment: @LetDoit Edited a bit.

Comment: @Suresh Sorry, can you explain little more about `To reduce the code duplication.` ? May be my mind not getting it quickly can you provide any hint?

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ It is important to note in your second example that although `Test` is a child class of `BigTest`, it is _also_ a child of `Object`... since `BigTest` implicity inherits from `Object`, and that inheritance is passed down to `Test`.

Comment: @LetDoit For example, every class in Java needs to be able to determine if it is equal to another class. Instead of requiring programmers to implement their own `Equals` method for every single class they write, Java provides a default implementation in `Object`, which (due to inheritance) every class has implicit access to. Of course, you are free to override that default implementation.

Comment: Ooohh Yeess.. Now Understanding why NetBeans provide the list of extra methods when I try to call any member of class using instance(object).

Comment: Exactly, those are all methods you got from Object class since you are a child of it :) @Nik G edited a bit now.

Answer (score 1):

It means that,in java the Object class is the parent class of all the classes by default. In other words, it is the topmost class or the base class of java. All other classes inherit the properties of Object class.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the following two classes are the same:

```
class MyClass {
}

class MyClass extends Object {
}
```

If a class definition doesn't specify `extends`, the class implicitly extends `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

The `Object` class comes with the JRE, you use any class without it. Java does this so you can have a reference to any object e.g.

```
Object o = x;
```

This works because no matter what `x` is, it is also an Object.

Note: even `int[]` class is a sub-class of `Object`.

Comment: Peter I'm thinking your answer is about to feature of Java Object, but I'm not understanding it, can you explain please?

Comment: @LetDoit can you give me a hint of what you don't understand?

Comment: Sorry I was confused now Understood.. It is same as C++ inheritance Parent class pointer could have reference of Child Object Understood.

Comment: @LetDoit There is a class all objects have to be a sub-class of, it's no more complicated than that.